# What tense form is this?

Tags: tense

> Aber jemand hat Sascha aus der Finanzabteilung vorbeilaufen *sehen*.

Should it not be *gesehen* instead? This way it would be the Perfekt tense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Aber jemand hat Sascha aus der Finanzabteilung vorbeilaufen ***sehen***.

This is a nice example of a peculiarity of German grammar called [*Ersatzinfinitiv*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ersatzinfinitiv).

According to the basic rules of verb inflection, perfect and pluperfect are formed with *haben* and *sein*, respectively, and the past participle. For some verbs, however, if the participle is preceded by an infinitive construction, the participle is replaced by the *Ersatzinfinitiv*. These verbs are

- all modal verbs
- *brauchen*, *heißen*, *lassen*, *helfen*, *fühlen*, *hören*, and ***sehen***

  <sup>(I am not sure if *schmecken* belongs to these, as well.)</sup>

Other examples are:

> - Er hat uns nicht anrufen *wollen*.
> - Wir haben nichts mehr tun *können*.
> - Du hättest es nicht (zu) machen *brauchen*.
> - Sie haben mich nicht gehen *lassen*.
> - Ich hab dich weinen *hören*.

Comment: Thank you. So, if it was "machen" instead of sehen in that sentence (or any other verb not from the list above) it would have simply been "gemacht", right?
In short, this is just Perfekt tense but those verbs above, when preceded by an infinitive, also becomes infinitive?

Comment: @EvilRaceHorse, exactly. The verbs above are special in this sense. Notice, however, that this "rule" is becoming more and more violated. That is, you often read or hear the participle for these verbs.